# return and newlines?

Tags: javascript, return

I was messing around with something today, where I'm returning a DOM tree. I was wondering if there was a way to have the code be like:

```
return
  '<div id="something"> \
     <p>Stuff</p> \
   </div>'
```

instead of:

```
return '<div id="something"> \
     <p>Stuff</p> \
   </div>'
```

just for aesthetic reasons - the first one looks better. I Googled it for about 10 minutes, then figured I ought to just ask those who know more than me.

Comment: Just to note: the first example isn't working for me, but the second one is, so that's why I posted...

Comment: The first one evaluates to `return; ...` so it returns nothing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript/805755#805755

Comment: Thanks everyone! All very great responses that got upvoted, and I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it isn't.

A new line after a `return` triggers semi-colon insertion, so the code is equivalent to:

```
return;
  '<div id="something"> \
     <p>Stuff</p> \
   </div>';
```

…and you return `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not. Javascript sees the return-on-a-single-line and inserts a semicolon, ending the control flow.

Answer (score 2):

What comes closest to what you want is probably

```
return '\
   <div id="something"> \
       <p>stuff</p> \
   </div>';
```

Other then that I don't think it's possible

Comment: Or perhaps `return (` + newline + string + `);`